# Python finditer or sub for large Unicode text

Tags: python, regex, python-unicode, python-re

I have to replace into a large Unicode text document multiple occurrences of tokens.
Currently I'm iterating over the words of my dictionary and replace with `sub` a compiled regex:

```
for token, replacement in dictionary.tokens().iteritems():
    r = re.compile(word_regex_unicode(token), flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)
    text = r.sub(replacement, text)
```

where my word regex is like

```
# UTF8 unicode word regex
def word_regex_unicode(word):
    return r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(re.escape(word))
```

This means that a new regex must be compiled and then a `sub` call will occur for every token if present or not in the document `text`.
As alternative approach one could use `re.finditer` to find occurrences of a token and then call `re.sub` if a token has been found:

```
for token, replacement in dictionary.tokens().iteritems():
    r = re.compile(word_regex_unicode(token), flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)
    for m in r.finditer(token, text):
        # now call sub 
        text = r.sub(replacement, text)
```

thus avoiding calls to `re.sub` when not actually needed.
The last approach could be improved using the `re.finditer` group result:

```
for m in r.finditer(token, text):
    # match start: match.start()
    index = match.start()
    # replace from start to end
    text = text[:index] + token + text[index + 1:]
```

Which is the faster approach among these ones?

Comment: how big is the document?

Comment: Hundred of mega bytes.

Comment: is it a file or an in-memory object? Also, do you want to write the result to a file or as an in-memory string? Are words to replace strictly ASCII or unicode?

Comment: The words are Unicode, so the regex is the one showed. Everything happens in-memory after reading the dataset from file. The dump to UTF8 file may occur, but the key point is the performance of the replacement that must occur in memory first.

Comment: since performance is an important part of the answer, is there an artificial dataset to test on?